# How to get document ID from Firestore upon a snapshot

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the documentId from a Firestore database.

My Firestore database looks like this:

```
- chatMessages
  - chatId
    - messageId // <-- I want to get this
      - Object: { text, user, sentAt }
```

I am retrieving the data as follows, which works, but am unable to figure out how to get the documentId:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("chatMessages").doc("chatMessages").collection(chatId).get()
.then((snapshot) => {
  if (!snapshot.empty) {
    const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      // const id = doc.getId(); // <-- how can I get messageId here?
      // return id;
    });
  }
})
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the id (messageId) for each document. I have tried the following, none of which have worked:

`doc.getId()`

`doc.documentId`

`doc.documentID`

How can I get the document ID of the documents I am returning as shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy. It's just `doc.id`